# How to sum the second column's values according to the first column's value in a pytorch tensor?

Tags: numpy, indexing, pytorch, tensor, pytorch-dataloader

I've a tensor in pytorch, its first column's value choice is limited, but its second column's value is freely chosen, e.g:

```
val = torch.tensor([[1,233],
                    [1,222],
                    [2,333],
                    [2,3234],
                    [2,3242],
                    [2,3234],
                    [3,234],
                    [3,234],
                    [4,323]])
```

Now I want to sum all values in the second column if their correspoding first column's values are same, the output should be as following:

```
output_val=torch.tensor([[1,455],
                 [2,10043],
                 [3,468],
                 [4,323]])
```

I want to use pytorch's tensor-support APIs to hanlde this task instead of using python's for/while loop programming because I've more than billions of records to do this kind of handling, the for/while looping code will consume more than several days, and any suggestion is welcom.
Thanks!

Comment: There might be a fully vectorized solution, but I can't think of one. How many unique values are there in the first column? You can use `torch.unique()` to discover the unique values, and then you can iterate over those unique values with a for loop. For each unique value `v`, you can get the rows whose first column matches said value `filtered = val[val[:, 0] == v, 1]`, and then you can sum over the second column of those indexed rows, `cur_sum = filtered.sum()`.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer There are many unique values, above 10 billion, in the first column, that's the reason I don't want to use loop to iterate over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for suggestions from @Shai and @Alexander-guyer, finally I've got the full solution to fully utilize the pytorch's parallel computing power（with its APIs） to do this kind of handling. The following is my final solution:

Input value tensor is:

```
val = torch.tensor([[1,233],
                    [1,222],
                    [2,333],
                    [2,3234],
                    [2,3242],
                    [2,3234],
                    [3,234],
                    [3,234],
                    [4,323]])
```

Now get its first and second columns into val0 and val1:

```
val0=val[:,0]
val1=val[:,1]
```

Now, use the torch.unique() to get its first column's unique values into uniq_val0, and **get the inversal_index into index0**:

```
uniq_val0, index0=torch.unique(val0, return_inverse=True)
zero_sum=torch.zeros(uniq_val0.shape, dtype=torch.int64)
```

Now, we could index_add_() to get the values' sum we want with the index0 we got from previous step:

```
output_val1=zero_sum.index_add_(0, index0, val1)
```

Now, we could stack the uniq_val0 and output_val1 togather, this is what we want:

```
output_val=torch.stack((uniq_val0, output_val1),-1)
```

Now, check the value, it's just what we want:

```
print(output_val)

tensor([[    1,   455],
        [    2, 10043],
        [    3,   468],
        [    4,   323]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`index_add_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.index_add_.html#torch.Tensor.index_add_), where your first column is the index and the second one is `src`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you provide more explanation? I've checked the TORCH.TENSOR.INDEX_ADD_() documentation, I found it's only about two tensors's addition, and we could use the index to choose which columns in the first tensors to be added with the second tensor's corresponding columns. I don't know how this API could help on my question. Lots of Thanks!

Comment: @ClockZHONG use an all zeros tensor as the second one.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the meaning of index in TORCH.TENSOR.INDEX_ADD_(), its value is the index of the first tensors on which the second tensor's corresponding dimenstion values will be added. Can you write some example codes to show it? Thanks really really much!!!!! This is a long-time painful problem for me.

Comment: Oh! @Shai， I got it finally. I'll sumerize it soon, and add some more more explanations on your answer and set it as the finally solution. Wait a moment and no worry about it. Thanks!

Comment: @ClockZHONG well done! I knew you can do it!

Comment: Hahaha !! Done, it's just what I want, I really really appreciate your and Alexander-guyer help here. Because in your and Alexander's description, I couldn't get the reversal index on those unique values, so I couldn't fix it, after revisiting the torch.unique() official description, I found it could return it, then that's the missed step I need. Very very cool!!!!!!!!!!! When I trying to edit your answer post, I found the stackoverflow locked it, so I create a new answer.